# Is the conditional densities of X given Y and X given a bijective function of Y equivalent?

Tags: data-transformation, conditional-probability

Suppose that I know the conditional density $$ f_{X\lvert Z}(x\lvert Z=z) $$
It is the same as knowing $$ f_{X\lvert Y}(x\lvert Y = y) $$
if I assume that $Z=g(Y)$?

Let say I have two continuous random variables $X\in A$ and $Y\in B$. They could be vectors or matrices, but they have the same dimensions $\dim(A)=\dim(B)=p$. I want to know the conditional density of $X$ given $Y$, denoted $f_{X\lvert Y}(x\lvert Y = y)$. For some reason, it is more convenient for me to work with a third variable $Z\in C$, $\dim(C)=p$. I know the following relationship $Z=g(Y)$ to hold. The mapping $g:B\mapsto C$ is bijective and continuously once differentiable. Under those conditions, it seems to me that the following is always true: $$ f_{X\lvert Y}(x\lvert Y=y) = f_{X\lvert Z}(x\lvert Z = g^{-1}(y)) $$

Indeed by using the ''change of variable'', I obtain: $$ f_{X\lvert Y}(x\lvert Y=y) = \frac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_Y(y)} = \frac{f_{X,Z}(x,g^{-1}(y))\Big\lvert\det\left(\frac{\partial g^{-1}(y)}{\partial y}\right)\Big\rvert^{-1}}{f_Z(g^{-1}(y))\Big\lvert\det\left(\frac{\partial g^{-1}(y)}{\partial y}\right)\Big\rvert^{-1}} = \frac{f_{X,Z}(x,g^{-1}(y))}{f_Z(g^{-1}(y))} = f_{X\lvert Z}(x\lvert Z=g^{-1}(y)) $$

If the result is exact, it would mean that the conditional density is invariant to bijective transformation of the conditioning.

I could not find any similar result in textbook or by googling. Is this result known? Is there something wrong with the proof or the hypothesis?

Comment: This question is confusing and does not make sense.

Comment: Hmmm, sorry may be I was not clear enough. I edited the post. Is it clearer now?

Comment: @MichaelChernick I disagree; this seems a perfectly good question.

Comment: They are the same so long as $g(Y)$ is invertible.

Comment: Thanks for the replies! Yes you are right about the inversion of $g(Y)$. I believe this is already implied here in the post since $g(\cdot)$ is differentiable, hence $g(\cdot)$ is continuous, plus $g(\cdot)$ is bijective: a continuous bijective function has necessarily an inverse. Anyway I don't edit the post as this is not the point I wanted to check, unless, of course, if I am wrong with my deduction.

Comment: I had a specific application in statistics in mind when I asked the question. Giving a second though, Isn't this result a nice justification for doing data transform in a regression setting?